# sql statement to find max value for each primary key record

Tags: mysql, max

I have such table, column "time" is unix time stamp

```
nid tid time       rtt
139 498 1450609031 0.013079
139 498 1450609033 0.013229
139 498 1450609035 0.012379
139 444 1450609065 0.012479
139 444 1450609165 0.012239
139 444 1450609265 0.023479
139 333 1450619265 0.014379
139 333 1450629212 0.012334
139 333 1450630265 0.023234
140 498 1450640265 0.015379
140 498 1450641212 0.035334
140 498 1450642265 0.025234
140 555 1450650265 0.055379
140 555 1450652212 0.025334
140 555 1450654265 0.055234

......
```

What I want is to first create a table like below using sql, making tid as the primary key column, including the largest time for each nid and tid pair

```
tid nid time        rtt
498 139 1450609035  0.012379
444 139 1450609265  0.023479
333 139 1450630265  0.023234
```

The final result I want is to sum up the rtt above, i.e. 0.012379+0.023479+0.023234=0.059092

Could anyone help me write a sql statement to achieve the result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I dun think this question is duplicate......

Comment: How come it is duplicate? I think @Marc B has some problems in his brain, very on9